# How to retrieve result of sendmessage in telegram bot while the request is fails [in php]?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I send a request to telegram bot by php in this way:

```
<?php
$res=file_get_contents($request);
echo($res);
```

When you send a valid $request I receive a feedback ($res) that says:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":***,"from":{"id":***,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"**","username":"*****"},"chat":{"id":*****,"first_name":"***","username":"***","type":"private"},"date":1505286416,"text":"test"}}
```

But when something is wrong in $request I expect to receive something like this from $res:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}
```

Instead I recieve a warning and $res is NULL:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(*******): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /home/test/public_html/test.php on line 2
```

What should I do to access response of telegram in $res?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get error response, you can't use `file_get_contents`, try cURL instead of it.

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getChat?chat_id=-1";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$result = json_decode($data, true);
```